# PHP Version 5.3.10 , missing finfo.php?

Tags: php, yii

i am using yii framework and i am trying to implement a CKEditor.
It was all good untill i needed to make the file upload/browse functions , i managed the upload but  the browse ...  for it i found this guide (its using an extension elfinder)
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ezzeelfinder/

The problem is when i click browse files -> http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/5905/problems.png
And the page the error is coming from 
/TutProject/index.php/page/page/fileUploaderConnector , here is whats in the stackTrace/application log

```
include(finfo.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]:
failed to open stream: No such file or directory
(C:\wamp\www\yii-1.1.10.r3566\framework\YiiBase.php:418)
Stack trace:
#0 unknown(0): spl_autoload_call()
#1
C:\wamp\www\TutProject\protected\extensions\ezzeelfinder\php\elFinderVolumeDriver.class.php(644):
class_exists()
#2
C:\wamp\www\TutProject\protected\extensions\ezzeelfinder\php\elFinder.class.php(191):
elFinderVolumeLocalFileSystem->mount()
#3
C:\wamp\www\TutProject\protected\extensions\ezzeelfinder\ElFinderConnectorAction.php(54):
elFinder->__construct()
#4 C:\wamp\www\yii-1.1.10.r3566\framework\web\actions\CAction.php(75):
ElFinderConnectorAction->run()
#5 C:\wamp\www\yii-1.1.10.r3566\framework\web\CController.php(309):
ElFinderConnectorAction->runWithParams()
#6 C:\wamp\www\yii-1.1.10.r3566\framework\web\CController.php(287):
PageController->runAction()
#7 C:\wamp\www\yii-1.1.10.r3566\framework\web\CController.php(266):
PageController->runActionWithFilters()
#8 C:\wamp\www\yii-1.1.10.r3566\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(276):
PageController->run()
#9 C:\wamp\www\yii-1.1.10.r3566\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(135):
CWebApplication->runController()
#10 C:\wamp\www\yii-1.1.10.r3566\framework\base\CApplication.php(162):
CWebApplication->processRequest()
#11 C:\wamp\www\TutProject\index.php(13): CWebApplication->run()
REQUEST_URI=/TutProject/index.php/page/page/fileUploaderConnector?elfinder_connector_options/YToxOntzOjU6InJvb3RzIjthOjE6e2k6MDthOjY6e3M6NjoiZHJpdmVyIjtzOjE1OiJMb2NhbEZpbGVTeXN0ZW0iO3M6NDoicGF0aCI7czoyOToiQzpcd2FtcFx3d3dcVHV0UHJvamVjdFx1cGxvYWQiO3M6MzoiVVJMIjtzOjE4OiIvVHV0UHJvamVjdC91cGxvYWQiO3M6NzoidG1iUGF0aCI7czozNzoiQzpcd2FtcFx3d3dcVHV0UHJvamVjdFx1cGxvYWRcLnRodW1icyI7czoxMDoibWltZURldGVjdCI7czo4OiJpbnRlcm5hbCI7czoxMzoiYWNjZXNzQ29udHJvbCI7czo2OiJhY2Nlc3MiO319fQ%3D%3D?cmd=open&target=&init=1&tree=1&_=1337086423129
```

I tried searching for this finfo.php in my framework folder but i didn't find it. My php version is 5.3.10 (i found out that it was an extension before 5.3 )
And from what i have googled , it seems like another guy had the same problem as me and here is what he had to say

> "Well I figured out my issue. Apparently the elfinder was trying to
>   automatically determine the mime type location. I changed it to
>   manually reference the file and all is well. Thanks for the excellent
>   extension!"

But i am still new to Yii so i have no idea how to do that , any help would be appreciated.
Post a comment if you need more information about anything.

EDIT : Oh and by the way , the ERROR in my screenshot , it says "Unable to connect to Backend"

EDIT-2 : Here is the widget i use.

```
$this->widget("ext.ezzeelfinder.ElFinderWidget", array(
    'selector' => "div#file-uploader",
    'clientOptions' => array(
    //    'lang' => "bg",
        'resizable' => false,
        'wysiwyg' => "ckeditor"
    ),
    'connectorRoute' => "/page/page/fileUploaderConnector",
    'connectorOptions' => array(
        'roots' => array(
            array(
                'driver'  => "LocalFileSystem",
                'path' => 'C:\wamp\www\TutProject\upload',
                'URL' => 'http://localhost/TutProject/upload/',
                'tmbPath' => $filesPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . ".thumbs",
                'mimeDetect' => "internal",
                'accessControl' => "access"
            )
        )
    )
));
```

In here -> 'connectorRoute' => "/page/page/fileUploaderConnector",
the first "/page" is the module i use in Yii , the second "/page" is the controller

One wierd thing i noticed and i think my problem comes from there , let me explain a little
I will show 2 links besides each other ,
the first will be generated from

```
'connectorRoute' => "/page/page/fileUploaderConnector",
```

the second will be generated from

```
'connectorRoute' => "/page/fileUploaderConnector",
```

Now , am not shure if its a bug but , take a look at the links below

```
http://localhost/TutProject/index.php/page/page/fileUploaderConnector/elfinder_connector_options/YToxOntzOjU6InJvb3RzIjthOjE6e2k6MDthOjY6e3M6NjoiZHJpdmVyIjtzOjE1OiJMb2NhbEZpbGVTeXN0ZW0iO3M6NDoicGF0aCI7czoyOToiQzpcd2FtcFx3d3dcVHV0UHJvamVjdFx1cGxvYWQiO3M6MzoiVVJMIjtzOjM1OiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0L1R1dFByb2plY3QvdXBsb2FkLyI7czo3OiJ0bWJQYXRoIjtzOjM3OiJDOlx3YW1wXHd3d1xUdXRQcm9qZWN0XHVwbG9hZFwudGh1bWJzIjtzOjEwOiJtaW1lRGV0ZWN0IjtzOjg6ImludGVybmFsIjtzOjEzOiJhY2Nlc3NDb250cm9sIjtzOjY6ImFjY2VzcyI7fX19?cmd=open&target=&init=1&tree=1&_=1337106505830
     http://localhost/TutProject/index.php/page/fileUploaderConnector?elfinder_connector_options=YToxOntzOjU6InJvb3RzIjthOjE6e2k6MDthOjY6e3M6NjoiZHJpdmVyIjtzOjE1OiJMb2NhbEZpbGVTeXN0ZW0iO3M6NDoicGF0aCI7czoyOToiQzpcd2FtcFx3d3dcVHV0UHJvamVjdFx1cGxvYWQiO3M6MzoiVVJMIjtzOjM1OiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0L1R1dFByb2plY3QvdXBsb2FkLyI7czo3OiJ0bWJQYXRoIjtzOjM3OiJDOlx3YW1wXHd3d1xUdXRQcm9qZWN0XHVwbG9hZFwudGh1bWJzIjtzOjEwOiJtaW1lRGV0ZWN0IjtzOjg6ImludGVybmFsIjtzOjEzOiJhY2Nlc3NDb250cm9sIjtzOjY6ImFjY2VzcyI7fX19&cmd=open&target=&init=1&tree=1&_=1337106612468
```

The thing to notice in these links is that in the first link ( thats the one using /page/page/... )  after fileUploaderConnector the next symbol is '/' and then after
elfinder_connector_options , there is a '/' again ,
BUT
in the second link ( the one from /page/... ) after fileUploaderConnector the next symbol is '?' and after elfinder_connector_options there is a '='

Now i think that somehow when the path includes a MODULE , the link gets messed up , so i tried to fix it and actualy i managed to get (atleast i think so ) a valid link ,

here is the link that i think is valid and generates output

```
http://localhost/TutProject/index.php/page/page/fileUploaderConnector?elfinder_connector_options=YToxOntzOjU6InJvb3RzIjthOjE6e2k6MDthOjY6e3M6NjoiZHJpdmVyIjtzOjE1OiJMb2NhbEZpbGVTeXN0ZW0iO3M6NDoicGF0aCI7czoyOToiQzpcd2FtcFx3d3dcVHV0UHJvamVjdFx1cGxvYWQiO3M6MzoiVVJMIjtzOjM1OiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0L1R1dFByb2plY3QvdXBsb2FkLyI7czo3OiJ0bWJQYXRoIjtzOjM3OiJDOlx3YW1wXHd3d1xUdXRQcm9qZWN0XHVwbG9hZFwudGh1bWJzIjtzOjEwOiJtaW1lRGV0ZWN0IjtzOjg6ImludGVybmFsIjtzOjEzOiJhY2Nlc3NDb250cm9sIjtzOjY6ImFjY2VzcyI7fX19&cmd=open&target=&init=1&tree=1&_=1337106612468
```

Its the same as the SECOND link , i just added another "/page" in the link , so here is the output

{"cwd":{"mime":"directory","ts":1337085846,"read":1,"write":1,"size":0,"hash":"l1_XA","volumeid":"l1_","name":"upload","date":"Today 12:44","locked":1,"dirs":1},"options":{"path":"upload","url":"http://localhost/TutProject/upload/","tmbUrl":"http://localhost/TutProject/upload/.thumbs/","disabled":[],"separator":"\","copyOverwrite":1,"archivers":{"create":[],"extract":[]}},"files":[{"mime":"directory","ts":1337085846,"read":1,"write":1,"size":0,"hash":"l1_XA","volumeid":"l1_","name":"upload","date":"Today 12:44","locked":1,"dirs":1},{"mime":"directory","ts":1337085846,"read":1,"write":1,"size":0,"hash":"l1_LnRodW1icw","name":".thumbs","phash":"l1_XA","date":"Today 12:44"},{"mime":"image/png","ts":1319019671,"read":1,"write":1,"size":142959,"hash":"l1_MWJpbC5wbmc","name":"1bil.png","phash":"l1_XA","date":"19 Oct 2011 10:21","tmb":1}],"api":"2.0","uplMaxSize":"2M"}

I did not post it as a code sample because its very long.

So here i came up with a secondary question
Since i think my link gets modified somehow  , any idea how to make that stop ? it changes "?,=" both for '/'.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `'mimeDetect' => "internal",` to the widget initialization options

Comment: I already have that , i will edit my question in a sec with more info.

Comment: Awesome. This has become a life saviour for me after a full day of research on this particular problem which occured when I tried it in online server while it was working on local server.
But instead I did this in ElfinderController actions settings instead of while widget initialization options.

Comment: And now this link also worked
http://dlsobardiya.gov.np/index.php?r=elfinder/connector&cmd=open&target=&init=1&tree=1&_=1405764322869

like it was working previously
http://localhost/freelance/dlsobardiya/index.php?r=elfinder/connector&cmd=open&target=l1_Z2FsbGVyeQ&init=1&tree=1&_=1405764426148